# PostGIS data is being stored incorrectly

Tags: elixir, postgis, phoenix-framework, ecto

So I have a really weird problem here. I send the LatLong as double from my mobile app to my `phoenix` backend. Backend has defined the type as `:geography` in migrations. Then I cast the data obtained from the frontend like this.

```
%Ecto.Changeset{
        valid?: true,
        changes: %{lat_long_object: %{latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude}}
      } ->
        point = %Geo.Point{
          coordinates: {latitude, longitude},
          srid: 4326
        }
        changeset
        |> put_change(:lat_long, point)
```

Above code is just for casting LatLong to point.
So what's happening is:

I send suppose X, Y from frontend

Backend log says it received X, Y correctly

The return of Repo.update returns me the `User` struct, and even that User struct has correct value

Now if I run `Repo.all(User)` in `iex`  or run `select ST_asText(lat_long) from users;`  in psql, my longitude has changed. And it doesn't also always change, it changes only for certain regions like SouthWest of USA. For most part it returns right data. What can it be?

Comment: One thing to check - latitude is y, longitude is x, so check the order of your arguments...

Comment: order is correct

Comment: Can you show examples of inputs that get changed? And to what values are these changed.

Comment: @Hauleth  @mlinth So the problem was as follows. `geo_postgis` library has order of coordinates as `longitude, latitude`. I was using them in the backwards order everywhere, so for most part my application worked well. It only failed when `long` value was more less than greater than 90 or -90. As I was storing them backwards, i.e. long value in lat field, and vice versa, values above 90 were getting converted in someway, something like and angle of 420 degrees is converted to 60.  I changed the order everywhere and now my problem is solved. Thanks to Elixir Slack Community.

Comment: Reason for above `Long -180~180  Lat -90~90`. So lat field can't store more than 90.

Comment: Might be an idea to post your comment as an answer and accept it, in case others have a similar problem.

Comment: @mlinth Sure, I'll do that. Thanks.